# Why won't the OpenSimplexNoise Processing library work?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to use this library called OpenSimplexNoise, made by GitHub user TheCodingTrain. But I immediately discovered that I couldn't use it.
I did some digging to try to figure this out on my own, and I discovered that the JAR file and the main folder should have the same name (for example, the library file would be named OpenSimplexName and the JAR file would be OpenSimplexNoise.jar), and the folder the JAR file is in should be called "library." Once I fixed these issues, OpenSimplexNoise appeared in the "Import Library" menu in the "Contributed" section. But once I clicked it, a bunch of code appears:

```
import japplemenubar.*;
import processing.awt.*;
import processing.core.*;
import processing.data.*;
import processing.event.*;
import processing.javafx.*;
import processing.opengl.*;
```

along with the error message:

**More than one library is competing for this sketch.**
The import japplemenubar points to multiple libraries:
**core** (C:\Program Files\Processing\processing.3.5.4\core)
**OpenSimplexNoise** (C:\Users**\Documents\Processing\libraries\OpenSimplexNoise).
Extra libraries need to be removed before this sketch can be used."

I tried removing japplemenubar, but the same issue appeared with processing.awt, so I tried removing that, but it just kept happening with each different import. I tried deleting it all and just typing "import processing.OpenSimplexNoise.*;", but it said "The import processing.OpenSimplesNoise cannot be resolved."

Does this mean that I'm just doing something wrong, or is this library no longer usable?

Comment: Wait, why are you asking us instead of asking on Daniel's [issue tracker for this library](https://github.com/CodingTrain/OpenSimplexNoise-for-Processing/issues)? If there's a bug, he can fix it and now the code works for everyone. If you're just doing something wrong, he can tell you that, too, as the person most qualified to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/CodingTrain/OpenSimplexNoise-for-Processing here's the link for the library.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamerans I thought about doing that, I wanted to make sure it wasn't a problem on my end. I didn't want to attempt to point out an issue only to find out I just didn't know how to install a library correctly, since it seemed like other people were using it just fine.

Comment: Don't put details to your post in the comments, [put them in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Also, open source works because we contact the people who maintain it when something doesn't work, unless they explicitly stated where to get support in their project readme/website/etc. Stackoverflow is basically your "I already searched and researched, and nothing I found helps". which for open source projects always also includes "and I posted on the issue tracker but I didn't get an answer for several days now"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend watching/following the videos linked in the README and understanding those:

- https://youtu.be/pI2gvl9sdtE
- https://youtu.be/U0TGZCEWn8g

The tutorials are how to put organize/compile a basic Processing library from scratch, not how to use library itself.

It would've been easier if a distribution zip would have been uploaded, but the point is learn how to generate it.

Downloading the library zip and unzipping in Processing won't work.

You need to:

1. (install [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) if you haven't done so already as part of the video tutorial)
2. clone / download the project on your computer
3. Import the project into eclipse: [image: Import project into eclipse]
4. Drag and drop the build.xml file into the Ant panel: [image: Show Ant Panel] [image: build.xml] [image: Ant view] (in my view I've got multiple Processing libraries, you might have just OpenSimplexNoise)
5. Press the green Play Icon to run the build.

Initially I ran into this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/George/Documents/eclipse/OpenSimplexNoise-for-Processing/resources/build.xml:107: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/George/Documents/eclipse/OpenSimplexNoise-for-Processing/resources/build.xml:141: /Users/George/Desktop/OpenSimplexNoise-for-Processing/lib does not exist.
```

Instead of trying to debug/fix the xml file I simply made the folder structure it wanted: a desktop folder named `OpenSimplexNoise-for-Processing` containing a `lib` folder.

Smooth sailing after this: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Part of the ant build is copying the library to Documents/Processing/libraries so you can simply run the examples from there:

[image: OpenSimplex example]

FWIW I've uploaded the compiled library [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/OpenSimplexNoise.zip).

If simply wanted to use noise in Processing the built-in [`noise()`](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) function would do the trick.

If you want Simplex Noise without compiling Daniel Shiffman's example library you could try [toxiclibs](https://github.com/postspectacular/toxiclibs/releases/tag/0021) and it's [`toxi.math.noise`](https://github.com/postspectacular/toxiclibs/tree/master/src.core/toxi/math/noise) package (also comes with an [example sketch](https://github.com/postspectacular/toxiclibs/blob/master/examples/core/math/SimplexNoiseTest/SimplexNoiseTest.pde)).

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this tutorial? I looked everywhere on the site for one but couldn't find anything that helped.

Comment: These are screenshots I took on my machine I provided the answer: I 'made' it :)
It is a compressed version of what I learned a while ago from https://github.com/processing/processing-library-template

Comment: No I mean you mentioned a tutorial. Was it a README or a segment in the 39-minute video tutorial?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: the README doesn't contain a step by step text version of the Processing library compilation process, but it does contain the two youtube video links. The youtube videos (39-minute video tutorial) explains the library compilation steps. The first clip does an overview [here](https://youtu.be/pI2gvl9sdtE?t=911), at this stage, still using the processing library template. The second video modifies the processing library template into the OpenSimplex library (and compiles it yet again). Have I answered your questions ?

Comment: Yes that helps. I just can't believe they buried the one thing I needed to know about *installing* a library in a video titled "how to *make* a library" and didn't put that critical piece of info anywhere else. Didn't even leave a time stamp to point me to the right section. This is so frustrating...

Comment: [If my answer was helpful vote it up, if it was the solution to your problem, mark it with the green check mark](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Sometimes (counterintuitively) you need to slow down to gain speed. You nailed the issue yourself: you were looking for a library to install, not to make. If you can't find the library in Processing's Contribution Manager (Sketch > Import Library > Add Library) or in the repo's releases ([example](https://github.com/runwayml/processing-library/releases)) then it's likely you'll need to compile from source.

Comment: ...I can put myself in your shoes and see how it can be frustrating but look on the bright side: If anything you've learned a lot more this then if you luckily landed on another Processing library that just worked. This knowledge will be more valuable on the long run then when something "works" but you don't really get why/how.